# How to include bootstrap in sublime2?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, sublimetext2

Hi I write the following code in sublime text 2

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Welcome To SpendWiz</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="SpendWiz/js/bootstrap3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="SpendWiz/js/bootstrap3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
    </script>
    <style>
    .jumbotron {
      background-color: #00bcd4;
      color: #fff;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>  
    <div class="jumbotron text-center">
        <h1>Welcome To SpendWiz</h1>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I have downloaded bootstrap-3.3.7-dlist and saved it in folder SpendWiz/js/. I have written the above code in the folder Spendwiz and when I try to run it, it shows the content but it doesn't add bootstrap. Can you guys please help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you save the code above in the folder SpendWiz, the links to CSS and JS should likely omit the “SpendWitz/” part. Look for exact errors in the console.

Comment: Sure,Thank you Idleberg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove SpendWiz/ because you said those files are  already in that folder. No need to specify that.